# What is your best solution to deal with the components in vue?

Tags: vue.js, data-binding, vuetify.js

I'm new at vue and I don't know how to structure things well yet.

I was doing my own small vue project which is a simple booklist app. It's just like a simple todo app but with more functions like edit, calendar, paging, , searching(book search api) etc.

As I am from a Java-Spring Framework(jsp, jstl, el, jquery) field,
my plan at the first place for booklist data handing is that making 2 components just like I did from Spring basic CRUD( list.jsp(to display the list), listForm.jsp(insert, read, update for 1 jsp and display corresponding data using jstl tag)

So I planned simply like this.

```
BookList.vue(parent) -> BookForm.vue(child)
```

then I faced an issue with the checkbox checked data. I do not know how to send the checked data only to child component. So I did everything in BookList.vue (not for the other functions). and for me, it's not looking good.

So what's your best suggestion for apps like this? Handle all the book related data in 1 component like I did? Or separate components for list and form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to split up components as much as it makes sense. Having everything in one component is a bad practice and will lead to unmanagable code.

I'd even go further than just having two components. The list and the form is a good start, but you can create a separate component for the book item, so your BookList displays multiple book components, etc.

The way to share data can be done via props. You pass data from the parent component into the child component via [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html). If you want to return data from the child component to it's parent you can do that via [events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html).
That works well for small application. Once it starts to get a little bigger and more complicated you should look into something like [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/). This is a data store that can be accessed from each of your components and gives you an easy way to share data across the application.

Comment: so if i use vuex, then should I get data from getters to each component? or .. should I get it from getters to the parent component only once then just keep send it down to the child components? If i get data to each component should I $emit  functions to paranet component ? I'm still very confusing with this data flow....

Comment: If you're using vuex I don't see any problems calling getters from your child components. Should you have a getter that is very slow it might be worth calling the getter once and passing it on via props but I've never run into a problem like that. Child components can also call actions/mutations to update data in the store instead of calling $emit to return it back to the parent component first.

Comment: hmm I see. Many thanks! I guess I've got tons of stuff to study! ;-)